# Remove symmetrical sections from model

Tags: modeling, mesh

So I want to remove square-like sections from this simple model. I want to remove sections like the ones shown in the pic. Kind of to make it seem like windows. The problem is, I don't know how to remove these sections symmetrically, and I want the sections to be spaced properly.

Which modifiers should I use to achieve something similar?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add a cube, use an array modifier on it (set it to 4), then on your plane use a boolean modifier set on Difference and target your cube. It could help to add a subdivision modifier set on simple on your plane too (prior to adding the boolean), in order to get enough geometry for the boolean modifier to work. You could also just have a mirror modifier on your plane and cut it manually, there is a ton of ways to do this :).